# Fragmentation in C++ with big chunks of data (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management

I have been developing my program using `malloc()` to allocate memory. However, my investigations made me think that I am facing a memory fragmentation problem.

My program needs 5 memory allocations of ~70 MB each. When I run my program using 4 threads, I need 5x4 memory allocations of ~70 MB each (and I cannot use less memory). At the end, I want to be able to use the 8 cores of my i7, this is, 5x8 memory allocations.

If I do 5x2 malloc()s, the program works. Not for 5x3 malloc()s.

I have been reading about `std::vector` and `std::deque`. I believe that `std::deque` is my solution for this problem, as `std::vector` allocates a big chunk of consecutive memory as `malloc()` does.

There any other solutions to explore or `std::deque` is my only solution?

---

### EDIT

OS: Windows 8.1 (x64)

RAM: 8 GB (5 GB of free space)

I detect `malloc()` errors by checking `errno == ENOMEM`

---

NOTE: `ERROR_MEM_ALLOC_FAILED` is one of the errors I generate when memory allocation fails.

A debug trace for the program with 4 threads (i.e. 5x4 `malloc()`s):

```
Start

Thread 01
(+53.40576 MB) Total allocated  53.4/4095 total MB
(+53.40576 MB) Total allocated 106.8/4095 total MB
(+0.00008 MB)  Total allocated 106.8/4095 total MB
(+0.00008 MB)  Total allocated 106.8/4095 total MB
Tried to allocate 267 MB
ERROR_MEM_ALLOC_FAILED

Thread 02
(+53.40576 MB) Total allocated 160.2/4095 total MB
(+53.40576 MB) Total allocated 213.6/4095 total MB
(+0.00008 MB)  Total allocated 213.6/4095 total MB
(+0.00008 MB)  Total allocated 213.6/4095 total MB
Tried to allocate 267 MB
ERROR_MEM_ALLOC_FAILED

Thread 03
(+53.40576 MB) Total allocated 267.0/4095 total MB
Tried to allocate 53 MB
ERROR_MEM_ALLOC_FAILED

Thread 04
Tried to allocate 53 MB
ERROR_MEM_ALLOC_FAILED

End of program
```

I tried to run the same thing but changing the order of the memory allocations, but no memory was allocated.

```
Start

Thread 01
Tried to allocate 267 MB
ERROR_MEM_ALLOC_FAILED

Thread 02
Tried to allocate 267 MB
ERROR_MEM_ALLOC_FAILED

Thread 03
Tried to allocate 267 MB
ERROR_MEM_ALLOC_FAILED

Thread 04
Tried to allocate 267 MB
ERROR_MEM_ALLOC_FAILED

End of program
```

---

### SOLUTION

The solution was to compile the application as a 64-bit application. Hence, probably it was not a fragmentation problem.

Comment: What happens when your program doesn't works (5x3 malloc's) ? Are you sure that it's the malloc that's failing ?

Comment: It would be good, if you can also elaborate on what are trying to achieve by allocating such huge arrays. Because, looking from different angle then it might be case that you do not require such allocations.

Comment: @Tryum yes, after every malloc I check if errno = ENOMEM

Comment: @sameerkn I perform mathematical opeartions, so I need those allocations

Comment: mathematical operations dont need much memory ... your statement is utter fantasy. Even computationally intensive operations only use the CPU itself and **very little** memory - sometimes its necessary to store large results before the computation can be continued ... and these usually arent bigger than a few hundred (or thousands) of bytes

Comment: As @gavinb suggested the memory access patterns can be analysed. For example: are the corresponding index of all the array accessed simultaneously i.e  for given index "i" do you access all the 5 array location    indexed at "i"? What's the relation between indexes in the arrays?

Comment: I run a correlation over a data-trace of 7M samples using double data type. For that, I have those requirements (5 arrays).

Comment: well ... you're doing it wrong. Also : what is "a data-trace" supposed to mean?

Comment: I have a bunch of 7M samples traces with associated data that have to be correlated. I do not think I am doing it wrong. What I think is that this going  a little bit offtopic.

Comment: no, in fact that seems to be a pretty basic computational problem - your dataset is large ... **too** large so there is a simple solution : segmentation. Split up your data and load it **on demand**, no matter how  fast that demand may change - you *will* have some overhead but thats simply the price for that solution. Welcome to IT 101. To be honest : i think you should let an actual developer continue your work ... because it may get rough from here on, advanced skills *may* be needed. Just a friendly suggestion from a professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you believe it's a memory fragmentation problem? Fragmentation is typically caused by allocating and deleting a large number of blocks of varying sizes, resulting in holes of available memory in between allocations that are not usable or useful sizes.  It does not sound at all like the pattern of memory access you describe.

Also, this amount of memory is not large by today's standards, though it depends on your hardware and operating system. How much physical memory does your machine have? What OS are you running? Is it build as a 32-bit or 64-bit app?  How do you know `malloc` is failing - is it returning `null`? Have you tried memory profiling?

```
Heap usage: 8 threads * 5 blocks * 70MB per block = 2800MB total
```

On Windows, the default per-process limit for heap allocations is 2GB for a 32-bit program, so it is quite likely to are hitting this limit. Probably the best solution would be to develop your app in 64-bit mode, then you can allocate huge amounts of (virtual) RAM.

> I have been reading about std::vector and std::deque. I believe that std::deque is my solution for this problem, as std::vector allocates a big chunk of consecutive memory as malloc() does.

No, using `std::vector` or `std::deque` won't necessarily solve your problem if it is either fragmentation or overallocation (most likely). They will both use `new/malloc` in their implementation to allocate memory anyway, so if you already know the bounds of your allocations, you might as well request the full amount up front as you are doing.

> There any other solutions to explore or std::deque is my only solution?

1. A `deque` is not a solution
2. Analyse your memory requirements, access patterns and reduce usage
3. If you can't get usage well below 2GB, switch to a 64-bit OS

Comment: I have answered some questions on my main questions. Currently I do not know if my app is 32 or 64 bits. I have not tried memory profiling, I will look for some information related to that.

Comment: I could compile my application as a 64-bit application. Now it is working. Thank you.

Comment: @McD0n3ld Good, glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much RAM you have. You need 5 * 70MB * 8 = 2800MB. There are some cases:

- If you have much more than that, it shouldn't be a problem to find it, even in contiguous blocks. I suppose you don't have so much.
- If, on the other hand, you don't have that much memory, no container will suit your needs, and there's nothing you can really do, other than adding RAM or modifying your program to use less cores.
- In the intermediate case, that is, your memory is not less than that, but not much more either, switching to another container might work but there are still problems: keep in mind that a vector is very space-efficient, as it is contiguous; any kind of linked list needs to store pointers to the next elements, and these pointers can take significant space, so you might end up needing more than 2800MB, although not in contiguous chunks. A `std::list`, from this point of view, would be terrible, because it needs a pointer to every element. So if your vectors hold a few, large items, switching to a list will give you a little overhead due to those few pointers, but if they are holding a lot of small values, the list will force you to waste a lot of space to store the pointers. In this sense, a deque should be what you need, as internally it is usually implemented as a group of arrays, so you don't need a pointer to every element.

To conclude: yes, a deque is what you are looking for. It will require more memory than vectors, but only a little, and that memory won't have to be contiguous, so you shouldn't have any more RAM fragmentation problems.

Comment: In virtual memory systems, the amount of RAM doesn't matter. The paging file size does.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Actually, the page table is in non-paged RAM so it does still matter.

Comment: @MSalters: if I am right, a page table entry is 8 bytes and a page 4 KB, so that 5.6 MB RAM is enough to map these 2.8 GB.

Comment: It's a hierarchy, so a bit more, but it's the right order of magnitude. Not relevant here, but it explains why you can't actually allocate 100TB on a 64 bit system.